# Changing 6 different random numbers with SRAND in a board made with Dynamically Allocated Arrays

Tags: arrays, function, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, srand

So, I have a code that creates a **7x7 board** with **Dynamically Allocated Arrays** and inside of a board is full with **"?"** and what I want to do is creating a new function and inside a function, I used **rand command** to get random numbers like this,

```
int random() {
    return ((rand() % 7) + 1);
}
```

Therefore, I had a problem changing 6 random numbers in a board and my Code is below,

**This one below is the one I tried to get random numbers for an Array,**

```
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    char *rando = (char *)malloc(7 * 7 * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        rand1 = random();
        rand2 = random();
        *(rando + rand1 + rand2) = '*';
    }
```

And this one is where **I printed the "?" signs** and also where I tried to change **6 different signs** and it only prints out **"else"** part ignoring the **"if"** for some reason

```
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (*(board + i + j) == *(rando + i + j))
                printf("| %c ", *(rando + i + j));
            else
                printf("| %c ", *(board + i + j));
            }
```

**And my whole code is this, it's kinda long but most of them are for a nice looking board**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int random() {
    return ((rand() % 7) + 1);
}

int main() {
    int i, j, k, rand1, rand2, b;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    char *rando = (char *)malloc(7 * 7 * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        rand1 = random();
        rand2 = random();
        *(rando + rand1 + rand2) = '*';
    }
    char *board = (char *)malloc(7 * 7 * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            *(board + i + j) = '?';
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        printf("%4d", i);
    }
    printf("\n  ");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("+---");
    }
    printf("+\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%d ",i);
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (*(board + i + j) == *(rando + i + j))
                printf("| %c ", *(rando + i + j));
            else
                printf("| %c ", *(board + i + j));
        }
        printf("|\n");
        for (k = 0; k <= 7; k++) 
            if (k == 0)
                printf("  ");
            else
                printf("+---");
        printf("+\n");
    }
}
```

**I pointed out important parts** that I'm stuck with but still not sure if there is a problem in other parts of my code so I showed it here, **just in case**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you allocate the 7x7 matrix as a single array of 49 characters.  Yet you do not index into this array with the correct formula. The element at position (`i`,`j`) is accessed as `*(board + 7 * i + j)`, not `*(board + i + j)`.

  It would be simpler to declare `rando` and `board` to point to a 2D matrix and use the `[]` syntax:

  ```
  char (*board)[7] = malloc(7 * sizeof(*board));
  ```

  and use `board[i][j]`.
- Furthermore, the `rando` array is uninitialized, so the program has undefined behavior when reading the contents of the elements that have not been set to `'*'` in the first loop. You must initialize this array with `'?'`. You can do this with `memset()`.
- the function `random()` returns an integer in the range `1` to `7` inclusive. You should instead compute pseudo-random coordinates in the range `0` to `6`. Remove the `+1`;
- the test in the board printing loop is useless: if the board element at position `i`,`j` is the same as in the `rando` matrix you print the `rando` element otherwise t board element. This always prints the board element.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int random(void) {
    return rand() % 7;
}

void init_board(char board[7][7]) {
    // board can be initialized with 2 nested loops or
    // a single call to
    //memset(board, '?', 7 * 7);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '?';
        }
    }
}

void print_board(char board[7][7]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%4d", i + 1);
    }
    printf("\n  ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("+---");
    }
    printf("+\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%d ", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            printf("| %c ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
        printf("  ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            printf("+---");
        }
        printf("+\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int b;

    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    char (*rando)[7] = malloc(7 * sizeof(*rando));
    if (!rando)
        return 1;
    init_board(rando);
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        int rand1 = random();
        int rand2 = random();
        rando[rand1][rand2] = '*';
    }
    char (*board)[7] = malloc(7 * sizeof(*board));
    if (!board)
        return 1;
    init_board(board);

    /* print the mines */
    print_board(rando);

    /* print the board */
    print_board(board);

    free(rando);
    free(board);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a little typo : you forgot to declare *k* in *print_board* (e.g. *int i, j,k;* rather than *int i,j;*)). UV anyway, yes I am too gentle :-)

Comment: Is it possible to do it without the strings?  I mean, without memset

Comment: @user9414: I used `memset` because the matrix base type is a byte type. You can write nested loops: `for (i = 0; i < 0; i++) for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) board[i][j] = '?';`

Comment: @bruno: answer updated. I also removed useless definitions in `main()`. This is a typical example of the advantage of using C99 `for` scoped index variables.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using C currently

Comment: @user9414: C99 **is** C. Very few compilers do not support C99 features. If your compiler compiled the code posted in the question, defining index variables in the `for` statement init clause should be fine: You already use a C99 extension, namely defining `rando` and `board` in the middle of a block.